# cakephp pass select value ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have two select buttons and want to filter records, when user select any option I have to fire a event and pass the values of buttons to the controller's action. my code is as under

view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee'); ?>
   <fieldset>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('designation', array("label" => "Designation",'type' => 'select', 'id'=>'DesignationType','options' => $settings,'empty'   => 'select'));?>

      <?php echo $this->Form->input('district', array("label" => "District",'type' => 'select', 'id'=>'districtType','options' => $district,'empty'   => 'select'));?>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); 

   $this->Js->get('#DesignationType')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'employees',
        'action'=>'getByCategory'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#success',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
        'isForm' => true,
        'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
    );
    ?>
 <div id="success"></div>
```

controller

```
public function getByCategory(){
      $design_id =$this->request->data['Employee']['designation'];
      $district_id =$this->request->data['Employee']['district'];         
      $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

when i click designation then i m  able to get the value of designation but not able to get the value of district .And following error occur

Undefined index: district [APP\Controller\EmployeesController.php, line 18]

so, how can i get the value of district;

Comment: Try adding `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();` after `$this->Js->request(..` call.

Comment: I wouldn't use the deprecated JS helper. See [ajax-and-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) and the linked "chained dropdown example" which is exactly what you are doing here - just using jQuery and CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send the `form id` in data variable. that is

Try this :

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#YourFormId')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));    
$this->Js->get('#DesignationType')->event('change',
$this->Js->request(array(
   'controller'=>'employees',
   'action'=>'getByCategory'
   ), array(
   'update'=>'#success',
   'async' => true,
   'method' => 'post',
   'dataExpression'=>true,
   'data'=> $data
   ))

);
```